# NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, varnish

***Apache Details***

Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 28 2015 22:18:57

***Varnish***

varnishd (varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2014 Varnish Software AS

***OS***

CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

***Linux Kernel***

2.6.32-042stab113.11 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 17:32:04 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Note:**
When trying to start getting this error and kindly advice how to solve these errors and start apache server. I have install and configure varnish cache proxy server also.

```
Failed to start apache :

Starting httpd: [Sat Mar 12 16:36:02 2016] [error] VirtualHost _default_:443 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Sat Mar 12 16:36:02 2016] [error] VirtualHost _default_:8443 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Sat Mar 12 16:36:02 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost 23.227.161.204:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat Mar 12 16:36:02 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost 23.227.161.204:81 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat Mar 12 16:36:02 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost 23.227.161.204:444 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 104.251.216.213:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[FAILED]
```

On browser request getting following error.

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable
Guru Meditation:

XID: 54055607

Varnish cache server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Apache is starting correctly, the Varnish error will go away. Currently Varnish is trying to get content from Apache but can't because Apache is down.

You should be able to solve the Apache error using the accepted answer of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/76766/how-can-i-solve-the-apache2-httpd-error-mixing-ports-and-non-ports-with-a-n).

Comment: You are correct and thanks but I was unable to start Apache. I will refer you link.