# Apache2 warning multiple Virtual Hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

My conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

It works, but I get this warning message on reboot:

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Anyone know why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Did you reload or restart apache after making the changes?)

Check to see if the NameVirtualHost line already exists elsewhere in the configuration

Comment: Yes, that's why I got the warning message "on reboot." The config worked (not sure what the issue was), but I still get the warning...

Comment: Check to see if the NameVirtualHost line already exists elsewhere in the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache 2 startup warning: NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/1405/apache2-startup-warning-namevirtualhost-80-has-no-virtualhosts)

See also this:
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/08/11/apache-warn-namevirtualhost-80-has-no-virtualhosts-error-when-start/